# Engine specifications for 10.2 liter Chevrolet V8

Tags: engine, chevrolet, engine-theory, horsepower

In an effort to design a theoretical engine capable of outputting 3000 horsepower, I was hoping to emulate the 10.2 liter Chevrolet V8.

What are the specifications for this engine? I was hoping for the cylinder bore & stroke, as well as the piston style, valve train, etc.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are wanting to know?

Comment: @Peter engine's full specs about cylinder bore, piston, crank and rod length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Designing IC engine](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/designing-ic-engine)

Comment: @JoErNanO yep. Same guy. Slightly different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Chev 622ci = 10.2l

I found dimensions for a Chev 632 cubic inch =10.3l

Stroke: 4.750"

Rods: 6.635"

Bore: 4.600"

Taken from here: http://www.jegs.com/p/Blueprint-Engines/Blueprint-Pro-Series-Big-Block-Chevy-632ci-815HP-800TQ/1321871/10002/-1

The horsepower output you're talking about would require forced induction. So turbocharged or supercharged.

Here's a twin turbo 3000 hp chev http://www.engineswapdepot.com/?p=3661

Comment: I've seen a lot of ads for 622ci which is right at 10.2L ... you may want to take a look at them and adjust your answer. I've not seen any at 3000hp, but it would only take a pair of twin turbo's to make it happen. (Haha - I said *only* a set of twin turbos, lol! As if that wasn't enough already!) Also, Top Fuel Dragster is more like *8,000hp* ... so we are well below that threshold.